# sql ms access select by date and genre

Tags: ms-access, datetime, select

I have two tables:

```
fID  Enamn   Fnamn bdate
1 Ronge Paus 49-05-14
2 Nesser Håk  50-07-26
3 Bods Thomas 51-05-02
```

And

```
ISBN     cathegory
123    Prosa
456    Poesi
789    Thriller
```

I am trying to select by date and cathegory. The writer shoult be born before year "1950" and the cathegory should be "Poesi"

The result should be:

```
ISBN cathegory  fID  Enamn   Fnamn bdate
456   poesi      1   Ronge   Paus  49-05-14
```

I have tried the followin:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bok, författare
WHERE bdate BETWEEN #01/01/40# AND #01/01/50# AND kategori = 'poesi'
```

But it didn't work :(

Comment: Is the Ronge record in the first table related to the Poesi record in the second table?

Answer (score 1):

You need a method to match a record from the first table to it's category in the second table.  I assumed ISBN is the primary key in the second table, so used it as a foreign key in the first table.

I am unclear about the table names, so I substituted my own names.  Notice I also assumed bdate is Date/Time data type.  Here's what my versions of the tables look like:

tblA:

```
fID  Enamn   Fnamn  bdate     fkey_ISBN
1    Ronge   Paus   49-05-14  456
2    Nesser  Håk    50-07-26  123
3    Bods    Thomas 51-05-02  789
```

tblB:

```
ISBN   cathegory
123    Prosa
456    Poesi
789    Thriller
```

Then, to get writers born before year 1950 for cathegory "Poesi", use this query:

```
SELECT
    a.fkey_ISBN,
    b.cathegory,
    a.fID,
    a.Enamn,
    a.Fnamn,
    a.bdate
FROM
    tblA AS a
    INNER JOIN tblB AS b
    ON a.fkey_ISBN = b.ISBN
WHERE
    a.bdate < #1950/01/01#
    AND b.kategori = 'poesi';
```

**Edit**: If ISBN is in fact the primary key of tblB, you may get better performance by using ISBN rather than kategori in your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE
    a.bdate < #1950/01/01#
    AND b.ISBN = 456
```

or if IBSN is text rather than numeric data type:

```
WHERE
    a.bdate < #1950/01/01#
    AND b.ISBN = '456'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll get back to it ASA I get my old version back from what I jsut sent in before I saw this answer.